# RxJS if-else like pipe filtering

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I'm not good with JS and RxJS, so if my question is stupid, sorry.

I have this code; not written by me:

```js
  prepare(): Observable<any> {
    const i = of({}).pipe(
      // Check if file type is image
      filter(() => isImage(this.file)),
      switchMap(() => this.generateThumb()),
      switchMap(() => this.resizeImage()),
      take(1)
    );

    return i
  }
```

But I need a second thing; if the file type IS NOT an image:

1. If the file IS an image, resize image & generate thumbnail.
2. If the file IS NOT an image only generate thumbnail.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

**EDIT: for AJT_82's comment**

I really do not know what's happening here. Why to create a observable first, pipe it, filter it etc.

So I tried to make it simpler:

```
if (isImage(this.file)) {
    this.resizeImage();
}
this.generateThumb();

return of(this);
```

which fails.

Comment: Could you show us what you have attempted to do to solve this issue?

Comment: @AJT_82 check edit

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `partition` operator:

It should looks like:

```js
const source = of({});
const [images, notImages] = source.pipe(partition(() => isImage(this.file));

merge(
  images.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.resizeImage()),
  )
  notImages
)
.pipe(switchMap(() => this.generateThumb())),
.subscribe(...);
```

Partition will. give you observable of images, and second observable of noImages

Apply `resizeImages` on images, merge images with noImages and apply `generateThumb` on merged observable

[link to docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html)

Comment: I have to go out now, will try when I'm back. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Sorry mate, I fotgot this post. I did not try your way bacause I did not need anymore, since my problem was actually caused by a bug on the library i used. I was trying to fix it but at last I found a way to fix itit with adding one if else. Thank you anyway.